# Object in an object?

Tags: ios, arrays, object, nsmutablearray

I have a class which consist of three strings and an array.

That array contains another object list.

when i try to access and add new object to that array, it do not work.

For instance;

```
CarList{

NSString *carName;
NSString *carId;
NSMutableArray *carTires;
}
```

CarTyres is another class

```
 visits = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    Visits * visit1 = [[Visits alloc]init];

    visit1.visitDate = @"13.07.2013";

    [visits addObject:visit1];

    Visits * visit2 = [[Visits alloc]init];

    visit2.visitDate = @"10.07.2013";

    [visits addObject:visit2];


    orderList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    OrderList *order1 = [[OrderList alloc]init];

    order1.monthName1 = @"Mart";
    order1.monthName2 = @"Nisan";
    order1.monthName3 = @"Mayıs";

    Orders *firstOrder = [[Orders alloc]init];

    firstOrder.orderName = @"Voltaren";
    firstOrder.monthCount1 = @"20";
    firstOrder.monthCount2 = @"43";
    firstOrder.monthCount3 = @"11";
    firstOrder.rangeMonthCount = @"74";

    [order1.orders addObject:firstOrder];

    [orderList addObject:order1];
```

at the last line object is not added.

How to solve it?

Comment: You have to initialize the carTires array first.

Comment: Bearing in mind the fact that code above wouldn't even compile in its current state, how you do know that the object isn't being added to the array?

Comment: i have written this code as pseudo code, just to tell the story, i will update with my code.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. (Otherwise, we're just clutching at straws.)

Comment: updated my code above

Answer (score 0):

change to this, hope this helps u :)

```
    //suppose u hav an instance
   CarList{

    NSString *carName;
    NSString *carId;
    NSMutableArray *carTires;
   }


   //in another class
   CarTire{

   NSString *tireName;
   NSString *tireId;
   }

   CarList * carlist = [CarList alloc]init];

  carlist.carName =@"Blabla";
  carlist.carId =@"idx234";

    CarTire *tire1 = [CarTire alloc]init];

   tire1.tireName = @"Blibli";
   tire1.tireId = @"idT211";

  [carlist.carTires addObject:tire1];//you are adding to CarList object array
```